# Psutil gives same storage data for directories irrespective of the content inside it. [python v3.8+]

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, directory, psutil

I have different smb shares mounted on my system. I need the storage data of each mountpoint. Iam using psutil to get the data. But for some reason, the data does not change for diff folders.
Ex: I have a folder /mnt/share_Mount1/. I have no data inside share_Mount1.

```
psutil.disk_usage("/mnt/share_Mount1/")
sdiskusage(total=231496658944, used=124153004032, free=95560650752, percent=56.5)
```

Then, another share. /mnt/share_Mount2. Here i have data, 4 files, each of 100Mb. But when i try to get the storage here, it still shows the same values.

```
psutil.disk_usage("/mnt/share_Mount2/")
sdiskusage(total=231496658944, used=124153004032, free=95560650752, percent=56.5)
```

But how can both be same when there should be some difference here. Clarification required. Am i going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: If issue `mount` it will show the same block device mounted on the two folders.

Comment: @stark The block size is bsize=1048576 for all the mounted folders. But how does this play a role in all the folders returning the same size , when the storage of each folder is different.?